# Hi I need to get data form table after click on detail of row. From one controller to another controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What i need to get is keyword which is in table. This table is in controller and i need this keyword get to another controller to input. I tried using `jquery` and `ajax` but it is not working. Please can you help me ?

**Table:**

```
    <table class="table-hover" id="myTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Klicove slovo
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Hledanost
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Konkurence
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Cena
                        </th>

                        <th></th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @item.klicove_slovo
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.hledanost
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.konkurence
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.cena
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", new { id_klicoveho_slova = item.id_klicoveho_slova })
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
```

**Form with input in next controller:**

```
          @using (Html.BeginForm("Detail", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @area = "Home", @role = "form" }))
                    {
                        <fieldset>

                            <!-- Form Name -->
                            <legend></legend>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="nazev_reklamy">Název reklamy</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <div class="editor-field">
                                        <input id="textinput" name="nazev_reklamy" type="text" value="@Model.allAdvert.nazev_reklamy"  class="form-control input-md" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="typ_reklamy">Typ reklamy</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <div class="editor-field">
                                        <input id="textinput" name="typ_reklamy" type="text" value="@Model.allAdvert.typ_reklamy" class="form-control input-md" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="cena_reklamy">Cena reklamy</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <div class="editor-field">
                                        <input id="textinput" name="cena_reklamy" type="text" value="@Model.allAdvert.cena_reklamy" class="form-control input-md" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="klicove_slovo">Klíčové slovo</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <div class="editor-field">
                                        <input id="textinput" name="cena_reklamy" type="text" value="@Model.allKeywords.klicove_slovo" class="form-control input-md" />
                                    </div>




                                </div>

                            </div>





                            <!-- Button (Double) -->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="button1id"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Dokonceni", "Home")">    <input type="submit" id="button1id" value="Pokračovat" name="button1id" class="btn btn-success"></a>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>

                    }
```

**and jquery and ajax:**

```
 <script>
            //alert('clicked')
            var myRows = [];
            var $headers = $("th");
            var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function (index) {
                $cells = $(this).find("td");
                myRows[index] = {};
                $cells.each(function (cellIndex) {
                    myRows[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
                });
            });
            var myObj = {};
            myObj.myrows = myRows;

            //alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Hledani",
                data: "objdata=" + JSON.stringify(myObj),//passing data as json
                success: function (result) {
                    //alert('exported');
                }
            });

    </script>
```

Comment: what ever you are mentioning as controller are actually Views, Your problem is to pass data from one view to another view.  So the route is  VIew--> Controller --> View. On click of the row id to a controller, your current code does that. Now your controller will receive this id and call a new view by passing this id, either use viewBag or pass it as a odel

Comment: Ok but how i get this id from view to controller and then to view to input ?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", new { id_klicoveho_slova = item.id_klicoveho_slova })` this code calls your controller right? by passing the data of `id_klicoveho_slova`